# Euler-Lagrange equations for a double integral

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

Consider a functional

$$
J[f] = \int_{a}^{b} \int_{a}^{y} \frac{e^{f(y) - f(x)}}{f'(x)} g(x,y) \, dx \,dy,
$$

where the constants $a$, $b$ and the function $g$ are given. I am looking for a function $f$ that minimizes this functional. I have tried to use the Euler-Lagrange equation, but I am unsure how to correctly apply it in this case. The difficulties are:

- There are two integrals, and the function of interest is nested within the inner one.
- The upper limit of the inner integral is not constant.
- Both $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are present within the functional.

I know that there exist various versions of the Euler-Lagrange equations, and would be very grateful if someone could point out which one could be used in this case.

Comment: You could always try to just derive the appropriate Euler-Lagrange equation by hand by considering an arbitrary variation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define $F(x,y):=f(x)-f(y)$ and $G(x,y):=g(x,y)\theta(y-x)$, where $\theta(\cdot)$ is the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function). Then, we may rewrite the functional $J$ as
$$
J[F]=\int_a^b\int_a^b{\cal L}(x,y,F,F_x)\,dxdy, \tag{1}
$$
where
$$
{\cal L}(x,y,F,F_x):=\frac{e^{-F(x,y)}}{F_x(x,y)}G(x,y). \tag{2}
$$
For this problem, the appropriate form of the [Euler-Lagrange equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation#Single_function_of_several_variables_with_single_derivative) is given by
$$
\frac{\partial \cal{L}}{\partial F}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial \cal{L}}{\partial F_x}\right)=0. \tag{3}
$$
Explicitly,
\begin{align}
(3)&\implies -\frac{e^{-F}}{F_x}G-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(-\frac{e^{-F}}{F_x^2}G\right)=0 \\
&\implies -2\frac{e^{-F}}{F_x}G-2\frac{F_{xx}\,e^{-F}}{F_x^3}G+\frac{e^{-F}}{F_x^2}G_x=0 \\
&\implies -2(F_x^2+F_{xx})G+F_xG_x=0. \tag{4}
\end{align}
Incidentally, it seems that $(4)$ does not have a solution, since $F_x(=f'(x))$ and $F_{xx}(=f''(x))$ depend only on $x$, whereas $G$ is a function of both $x$ and $y$.

Comment: While other answers address the problem from first principles (which is great), this one actually answers the question as it was posed. I accept it.

Answer (score 2):

1. OP's functional reads
   $$ J[f]~=~\iint_{[a,b]^2}\!\mathrm{d}x~\mathrm{d}y~\frac{e^{f(y) - f(x)}}{f'(x)} g(x,y)\theta(y\!-\!x),\tag{1}$$
   where $\theta$ denotes the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).
2. Assuming pertinent Dirichlet boundary conditions an infinitesimal variation is
   of the form
   $$\begin{align} \delta J[f]
   ~\stackrel{(1)}{=}~&\iint_{[a,b]^2}\!\mathrm{d}x~\mathrm{d}y~(\delta f(y)-\delta f(x)) \frac{e^{f(y) - f(x)}}{f'(x)} g(x,y)\theta(y\!-\!x)\cr
   &-\iint_{[a,b]^2}\!\mathrm{d}x~\mathrm{d}y~\delta f^{\prime}(x) \frac{e^{f(y) - f(x)}}{f'(x)^2} g(x,y)\theta(y\!-\!x)\cr
   ~=~&\int_{[a,b]}\!\mathrm{d}x~\delta f(x) \int_{[a,b]}\!\mathrm{d}y~ \left(\frac{e^{f(x) - f(y)}}{f'(y)} g(y,x)\theta(x\!-\!y)
   \right.\cr &\qquad -\left.
   \frac{e^{f(y) - f(x)}}{f'(x)} g(x,y)\theta(y\!-\!x) 
   \right.\cr &\qquad +\left.
   \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{e^{f(y) - f(x)}}{f'(x)^2} g(x,y)\theta(y\!-\!x)\right)\right).\end{align}\tag{2}$$
3. Therefore the [functional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) is
   $$\begin{align} \frac{\delta J[f]}{\delta f(x)}~\stackrel{(2)}{=}~&\int_{[a,b]}\!\mathrm{d}y~ \left(\frac{e^{f(x) - f(y)}}{f'(y)} g(y,x)\theta(x\!-\!y)
   \right.\cr &\qquad -\left.
   \frac{e^{f(y) - f(x)}}{f'(x)} g(x,y)\theta(y\!-\!x)
   \right.\cr &\qquad +\left.
   \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{e^{f(y) - f(x)}}{f'(x)^2} g(x,y)\theta(y\!-\!x)\right)\right).\end{align}\tag{3}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I believe that $\theta$ is the Heaviside step function, and I find it very clever to use it. However, the second step is not quite clear to me. Could you please explain it in more detail? Naively speaking, why does there appear 2 almost identical terms with the swap $x \leftrightarrow y$? It looks like Newton-Leibniz, but I don't quite understand it. I would really appreciate it if you could elaborate on the derivation for the second step.

Comment: I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Recalling that, in the present case, the functional derivative is taken as
$$
\frac{\delta}{\delta f} \equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial f} - \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \frac{\partial}{\partial f'} 
\quad\mathrm{with}\quad 
\frac{\delta f(x)}{\delta f(x')} = \delta(x-x'),
$$
where the last $\delta$ denotes the Dirac delta function, one has :
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \frac{\delta J[f]}{\delta f(z)} 
   &=& \displaystyle
   \int_a^b\mathrm{d}y \int_a^y\mathrm{d}x \left(\frac{e^{f(y)-f(x)}}{f'(x)}(\delta(y-z)-\delta(x-z)) - \frac{e^{f(y)-f(x)}}{f'(x)}(1+2f''(x))\delta(x-z)\right) g(x,y) \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \int_a^b\mathrm{d}y \int_a^y\mathrm{d}x \left(\frac{e^{f(y)-f(x)}}{f'(x)}(\delta(y-z)-2(1+f''(x))\delta(x-z)\right) g(x,y) 
\end{array}
$$
Then, the Dirac deltas will "kill" some integrals depending on whether $z$ lies within the domains of integration.

---

**Edit** (see comments below) :

The functional differential is given by
$$
\delta J[f(x)] = \frac{\partial J}{\partial f}\delta f(x) + \frac{\partial J}{\partial f'}\delta f'(x),
$$
hence
$$
\frac{\delta J[f]}{\delta f(z)} = \frac{\partial J}{\partial f}\frac{\delta f(x)}{\delta f(z)} + \frac{\partial J}{\partial f'}\frac{\delta f'(z)}{\delta f(z)},
$$
with
$$
\frac{\delta f'(x)}{\delta f(z)} 
   = \frac{\delta}{\delta f(z)}\frac{\mathrm{d}f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x} 
   = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{\delta f(x)}{\delta f(z)} 
   = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\delta'(x-z) 
   \equiv -\delta(x-z)\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}
$$
where the last line is due to an integration by parts. In consequence, one gets :
$$
\frac{\delta J[f]}{\delta f(z)} = \delta(x-z)\left(\frac{\partial J}{\partial f} - \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{\partial J}{\partial f'}\right)
$$
In the present case, one has
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial f'} \frac{e^{f(y)-f(x)}}{f'(x)} = -\frac{e^{f(y)-f(x)}}{f'(x)^2}
$$
and
$$
-\frac{e^{f(y)-f(x)}}{f'(x)^2} \frac{\delta f'(x)}{\delta f(z)} 
   \equiv \delta(x-z)\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \frac{e^{f(y)-f(x)}}{f'(x)^2} 
   = -\delta(x-z)(1+2f''(x))\frac{e^{f(y)-f(x)}}{f'(x)}
$$
Note that there is no derivative with respect to $y$ because $f'(y)$ doesn't appear within the functional.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I have two minor questions and one big one. 1. Shouldn't it be $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}$ instead of $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}f}$ in the definition of the functional derivative? 2. Probably, the differentials $\mathrm{d}x$ and $\mathrm{d}y$ should be swapped? 3. (This is the big one). Could you please explain how you got the second part of the expression? I think I understand the part that comes from $\frac{\partial}{\partial f}$. However, I can't follow the second part, specifically where the factor $(f'(y)-f'(x))\delta(x-z)$ comes from.

Comment: @Zeekless Sorry, I was careless, I wrote this answer in a hurry and I made a bunch of errors. I have corrected the points you mention and I have added an edit to explicit the derivation of the third one.